# How to remove space between the map frame

Tags: html, css, iframe

I'm trying to build a site with some bootstrap styles and some grids.

I would like to have on the right part the Google Maps Card and on the left one a simple text.

The problem that I have is, that I have on mobile devices a space between the Google iframe and the grid. I gave it the color blue, so I can see where which grid isб but how can I fix it, that the Google Map takes the full width of the grid, without the space around it, which you can see on mobile devices ? [here is the demo site](http://limo.awesom-media.de)

```
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 gmap" style="background-color:blue">
            <iframe src="   https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d2369.3387871906875!2d9.987669999999998!3d53.56956999999999!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x47b18f10c1641aa5%3A0x9e2e0a1e8cac2d78!2sT%26M+Limousinen+Service+GmbH!5e0!3m2!1sde!2sde!4v1403018648499" width="100%" height="50%" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>  

            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            </a>
        </div>


.gmap{ padding: 0; height:15%;}
```

Comment: Please provide **relevant** code in your question. Once your issue is solved your link becomes useless, as the problem will no longer exist for future readers to see

Answer (score 0):

well try to order with the table tag.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            asdasdasd asdasdasd asdasdasd asdasdasd asdasdasd asdasdasd
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

        <td>
            a la derecha
        </td>
        <td style = "background-color:blue">

        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 gmap" style="background-color:blue">
                <iframe src="   https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d2369.3387871906875!2d9.987669999999998!3d53.56956999999999!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x47b18f10c1641aa5%3A0x9e2e0a1e8cac2d78!2sT%26M+Limousinen+Service+GmbH!5e0!3m2!1sde!2sde!4v1403018648499" width="100%" height="50%" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>  

            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

i was trying this and is a simple solution, you can add some styles to your table and the others inners tags, hope helped you.